# までは vs まで difference

Tags: word-choice

What's the difference between saying for example
限界までは我慢する and 限界まで我慢する
I did googled a bit but can't find any relevant answers

Answer (score 1):

This is just the topic/contrast marker は attached to the end of まで. The topic marker は can also be used for emphasis or contrast. In this case, it's similar to saying "only until" instead of just "until". For example:

> 明日まで我慢する。
> I will endure it until tomorrow

The above sounds like a simple statement. Maybe you are in pain, and the painkillers won't be delivered until tomorrow.

> 明日までは我慢する。
> I will only endure it until tomorrow.

Here, は emphasizes 明日まで. Depending on context, this can mean different things. Maybe there is someone bothering you at work, and you already reported it to upper management, but they tell you that they are busy and will deal with the harassment later. This would mean something along the lines of "I'll endure it, but only until tomorrow."